# How should I denote subelement of some object.

Tags: notation

For example I have set of graphs $S = \{G : G = (V, E)$} and I want to say in "math notation" that none of S's graph V is not empty. In other words I want to address the subelemnt of G like I do it in java: `G.V`. Is this notation is correct? Can I write something like this: $\forall G \in S: G.V \neq \emptyset$ ?

Comment: This notation is not used in math, and actually the notion of "subelement" is not even defined.

Comment: But how can I write my expression in this case?

Comment: You need to say something like this. "For all $G \in S$ we denote by $V(G)$ the set of vertices of the graph $G$. Then for all $G \in S, V(G) \neq \emptyset$" . I think that you might find this unsatisfactory... well, I don't see any other way to say this.